# Wrapper autoboxing

Tags: java, wrapper

```
public class Wrap
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
Integer a =1000;
Integer b =1000;
System.out.println(a == b);   //line 7
Integer c = 10;
Integer d = 10;
System.out.println(c == d);   // line 10
}
}
```

**Understood part:** In line 7 it is comparing  whether reference variable referring  to same object or not. And in line 10 its comparing the actual primitive data that wrapper object holds.

**What I found:** If value is between -128 to 127 it will compare primitive value or else check whether reference variable is referring to same object

**My question:** Why is it so? Is there any logic involved? Is that logic of any use? Or is 
it just an oracle way to say how java is different from other languages.

Comment: 1000 may of may not do this. Try `-XX:+AggressiveOpts`

Comment: There is some caching involved, for some odd reason, that is why the compare works for that range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Understood part: In line 7 it is comparing whether reference variable referring to same object or not.

correct

> And in line 10 its comparing the actual primitive data that wrapper object holds.

No, it does exactly the same thing.

> What I found: If value is between -128 to 127 it will compare primitive value or else check whether reference variable is referring to same object

This is the default range for the Integer cache. This is true for other integer types and Boolean.

> My question: Why is it so?

To improve performance.

> Is there any logic involved?

See Integer.valueOf(int)

> Is that logic of any use?

Saves garbage.

> Or is it just an oracle way to say how java is different from other languages.

Perhaps, Sun's idea really.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more on what integer cache is and how it saves garbage

Comment: @RohanPujari The Integer cache, caches Integers. i.e. instead of giving you a new one each time it gets one from an array.  It saves garbage by not giving you a new object each time and reusing ones it has in its array.  You want to do this because although creating objects is cheap, do it enough and it adds up.  Not creating an object can be 5x faster.